# Python Pathlib path object not converting to string

Tags: python, shutil, pathlib

I am trying to use Shutil to copy a pdf file using path objects from Pathlib, however when I run my code I get the error "str object is not callable"
when converting my paths back to strings using str(). Any explanation for why this is occurring would be very helpful. Thanks!

```
from pathlib import Path
from wand.image import Image as wandImage
import shutil
import sys
import os

def pdf2Jpeg(pdf_path):
    pdf = pdf_path
    jpg = pdf[:-3] + "jpg"
    img = wandImage(filename=pdf)
    img.save(filename=jpg)

src0 = Path(r"G:\Well Schematics\Well Histories\Merged")
dst0 = Path(r"G:\Well Schematics\Well Histories\Out")
if not dst0.exists():
    dst0.mkdir()

pdfs = []
api = ''
name = ''
pnum = ''
imgs = []

for pdf in src0.iterdir():
    pdfs.append(pdf)

for pdf in pdfs:

    if not dst0.exists():
        dst0.mkdir()

    str = str(pdf.stem)
    split = str.split('_')
    api = split[0]
    name = split[1]
    pnum = split[2]

    shutil.copy(str(pdf), str(dst0))
    for file in dst0.iterdir():
        newpdf = file
    pdf2Jpeg(str(newpdf))
    newpdf.unlink()
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
str = str(pdf.stem)
```

You're overwriting the value `str`, so starting from the 2nd iteration of your loop, `str` no longer refers to the built-in `str` function. Choose a different name for this variable.

Comment: Path.stem returns a str object anyway, so you could simplify this further by doing: split = pdf.stem.split('_')

Comment: refrain from using built-in functions https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html as namespaces for any objects.

Comment: You can also do `Path(path_here).as_posix()`

Comment: it is better to write a mini-function for that. Because if the variable path is None or another type: the str() will return always the cast of that variable like ‘None’. The solution is:


`#
def path_object_to_str(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, pathlib.Path):
        return str(obj)
`